# FDQuery quais os riscos em usar variável no lugar de Parâmetro

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

Estou fazendo uma conexão pra buscar dados dentro do banco com uma condição `IN()`, porém tive dificuldades em implementar isso entre `FDQuery` e o *FireBird*.

Analisando o problema percebi que comando *SQL*  estava chegando ao banco em uma condição que era impossível de ser executada, ou nem era aceita pelo `FDQuery`. Tentei varias formas de tratativa e não deram certo.

Ai apelei pra o que considero como um P.O.G. criando uma variável `String` inseri ela no meio do *SQL* com os dados devidamente tratados para que ela fosse recepcionada no banco da forma que o *FireBird* consegue executar.

```
FDconsult.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM PED1A WHERE ID_LOJA IN (');
FDconsult.SQL.Add(consulta);
FDconsult.SQL.Add(')');
FDconsult.Open;
```

Quais riscos ofereço a minha aplicação fazendo esse tipo de P.O.G.?

Comment: Depende, como você obtém o conteúdo da variável `consulta`? Pode colocar a forma como você estava fazendo e como estava chegando no banco?

Comment: Por questões de lógica não teriam problemas, mas dependendo do banco de dados utilizado pode perder um pouco em questão de performance. Não sei como o firebird trata este caso, mas em determinados bancos, quando a consulta é executada com parâmetros o banco já salva o plano de execução e a próxima vez que a consulta for executada o mesmo não precisa ser feito novamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizamos aqui Firebird também, e te asseguro que não existe risco, até porque tudo se trata de string pura que somente mais tarde será processada pelo banco de dados.

```
FDconsult.SQL.Clear;{Dependendo do componente é ..SQL.SelectSql.Clear}
FDconsult.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM PED1A WHERE ID_LOJA IN (' + consulta + ')');
FDconsult.Open;
```

Da na mesma. Por parâmetro acho meio difícil você utilizar o `IN`, utilizávamos apenas na cláusula `WHERE` e trocamos todos para `string` pura.

Lembrando que se o campo `ID_LOJA` for *varchar* todos os items de `consulta` devem estar entre aspas duplas.

Comment: `consulta := 'SomeValue); DROP DATABASE dbName;'`??

Comment: @Sami, Neste caso ai vai dar erro de sql, porém ele esta falando de `riscos` e não de falhas de segurança, pois, da mesma forma, o parâmetro é uma string também, mais um detalhe é que `consulta` seria itens que ele alimenta internamente para passar como "parâmetro" para a execução do SQL. Agora, quem permite que usuário que faz consulta pode realizar um DROP a falha não esta na execução, e sim na permissão.

Answer (score 2):

Não vejo riscos na utilização de `string` no lugar de `params`.
Porém vejo benefícios na utilização de parâmetros, especialmente se seu sistema é ou algum dia será multibanco.
Isso devido o `FireDAC` já alterar por exemplo um parâmetro de data para o formato aceito pelo banco conectado.
Se desejar continuar usando `params`, para solucionar a questão do `IN`, vc pode usar as MACROS (`MacroByName`), que é um misto de `string pura` com `params`.